# Python - array incrementation with column block after certain value

Tags: python

I've been trying to create array "matrix" with 5 elements and increment in specific way.

```
matrix=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    matrix.append(0)

matrix[4]=0x0A
i = 1
print matrix
while True:
    matrix[0]=i&0xFF
    matrix[1]=(i>>8)&0xFF
    matrix[2]=(i>>16)&0xFF
    i += 1
    print matrix
```

I wanted it to count up to 255 (first element) > block the first column and count up to 255 etc. At the moment after reaching 255 value in the first column it restart it value and increase the second column by one. Do you know how to solve this problem?
Here is the result
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9hq6.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what "block the first column" means. Can you elaborate? Perhaps, give an example of the desired output.

Comment: i want it to be more like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/IFnTNbz) instead of this [link](https://imgur.com/a/H08Pajq)

Comment: this program restart the value of first column after reaching 255 instead of moving to second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In This solution you can reach the given number from 0 (up to 1023) with step of 256bits. After reaching given value (like 256) it set the value of matrix[0] to "255" and starts adding to the matrix[1].

Here is the demo for this program. [link](https://ideone.com/6YtO85)

```
matrix=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    matrix.append(0)  

x = 1
counting = 1

print matrix
while True:
    if (x >= 1023):
        counting = -1
    matrix[0]=x&0xFF
    x += counting

    if (x >= 256):
        matrix[0] = 255
        matrix[1] = x&0xFF
    if (x >= 512):
        matrix[1] = 255
        matrix[2] = x&0xFF
    if (x >= 768):
        matrix[2] = 255
        matrix[3] = x&0xFF
    if (x == -1):
        counting = 1
    print matrix
```